# Is 2,5-dimethylidenecyclopent-3-en-1-ide aromatic?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

Ah yes, the age-old question.

I understand from previous posts on this website that aromaticity can't be defined with using four rules. But I was curious about this particular anion:

[image: 2,5-dimethylidenecyclopent-3-en-1-ide]

It certainly follows all the rules (6 π electrons, cyclic, planar, fully conjugated), but is it really aromatic?

Comment: Fully conjugated? This is cross-conjugated - no more aromatic than quinone.

Comment: Pendant pi bonding means you can't rely on the 4n+2 rule. Some species with pendant pi bonds are aromatic, but it is much harder to predict than just applying the 4n+2 rule which applies only to things that are **exactly conjugated cycles.**